# GPU Clocks Up If a Hardware-accelerated Program is Running while Gaming

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hardware-acceleration

I have a GTX1060 (Gigabyte), BIOS firmware version 86.06.39.00.50 and the most recent Nvidia drivers, updated and reinstalled (clean), running on Windows 10 64 bit. Here is the problem:

When a 3D game capped at 1080p 60fps is running the card can easily remain at a clock speed of 925-1300MHz and voltage of 0.625-0.7V. This is good, it is how it should be. HOWEVER if ANOTHER program with hardware acceleration is opened at the same time as the game, the GPU ramps up to maximum clock speeds and voltage (1900MHz+ and 1V+) for no reason, wasting ~40W+ of power out of the wall and heating up the GPU unnecessarily.

I can trigger this by opening any web browser with hardware acceleration enabled, no need for any tabs to be open, or **ANY other program** with the setting available. Things like Discord, with its UI HW acceleration option trigger the problem, or enabling my video player's HW acceleration.

Those programs create no problem running on their own, I can have 3 HW accelerated browsers running at the same time and the GPU is fine. The issue is when even ONE is open, even minimized, while a semi-demanding 3D game is running.

When the problem is occurring, **the HW accelerated program isn't actually putting any extra load on the GPU**. I know this because if I turn off V-sync I get the same max FPS with or without the HW accelerated program running. In the Nvidia Control Panel I'm using Optimal power setting, of course.

Normally I can just keep browsers closed, but this has now become a problem, because seemingly GTA V's Social Club UI has hardware acceleration enabled and I can't turn it off or run the game without it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you describe is actually normal.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for commenting. But it's so wasteful, it doesn't make any sense. Why should my GPU be wasting 40W + just because there's a minimized browser, or because Discord for some reason has HW acceleration in its gui, sitting in the taskbar?

Comment: Probably, even when minimized, if an application is still using cpu time, even basic record keeping or NOP is going to cause usage and they cannot suspend if they are push/polling. They don't for example release their gpu contexts when minimized (though they might "release" all their assets: some games resume immediately, some take forever). Even a very brief amount of time may require some record keeping which may involve overhead: in order to do "nothing" there is still overhead when switching before there is a "nothing to do." A process might consume *more* gpu minimized (vsync not honored)

Comment: @Yorik But this is absolutely negligible. If I remove V-sync in my game they don't affect my performance at all, I still get the same FPS. They're just somehow fooling the GPU into thinking it needs to be ready for a lot more than it will actually need to handle. I need to somehow deny a specific executable this attempt to hijack my GPU for absolutely nothing.